# git post-receive hook doesn't seem to process other branches

Tags: git

I hope you guys are doing wonderful in your lives. I am not very expert with git but I love it very very much ever since I started using it.

I have two repositories on my client's server namely `live.git` and `beta.git` and by following some tutorials on the internet I was able to setup hooks, post-receive one, to create a working directory for the files (to `/` and `/beta/` directories respectively). The project is a web app so whenever I make changes I simply push them to the repositories and the post-receive hook updates the files in the working directory.

The issue is I recently created a new branch (called `Angular`) and now if I do

```
git push beta Angular
```

It does push the updates to the repository, but now the working directory is not affected. The working directory still shows the changes from the `master` branch.

These are the contents of my post-receive hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Performing post-receive actions on beta.."
git --work-tree=/home/webapp/public_html/beta --git-dir=/home/webapp/public_html/beta.git checkout -f
```

I do not see any mention of `master` or any branch here that's why I am unable to even try something different here.

Can someone please help me understand how can I make it so that no matter which branch is pushed, it simply updates the files in the working directory based on the last branch that was pushed?

Thank you all in advance and for your time.

**Edit:**
My questions are:

1) Why does it process `master` branch my default?

2) Is there any config that specifies somewhere that only `master` branch is processed by default with the `git --work-tree` command?

3) Is there anyway to perhaps hardcode which branch to write to the `work-tree`? Because I will probably only push on branch to the `beta.git` and another branch to the `live.git` almost always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone please help me understand how can I make it so that no matter which branch is pushed, it simply updates the files in the working directory based on the last branch that was pushed?

What if I run, e.g.:

```
git push origin branch1 branch2 branch3
```

?  Which branch do you want deployed, given that I just updated three branches with a single push?

In any case, the answer is a little bit complicated.  Part of it is very easy: *any* post-receive hook can, and most should, read *each line* from the standard input.  Each such line acts as a directive, as documented in [the githooks manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html).  The input format is the same as for [the pre-receive hook](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#_pre-receive), so read that section as well.

You can find many post-receive deployment hooks through [google search](https://www.google.com/#q=git+post-receive+deployment&*), but many of them are broken—some a bit subtly.  The first three I checked were all wrong: one had the same issue yours does (not reading stdin), and two read stdin but checked for references *ending in* `master`, which means that if I did:

```
git push origin sneaky/master
```

they would treat my branch `sneaky/master` as if it were the regular old `master` branch.  Moreover, *any* reference, including a tag, named or ending with `master` would do the same thing.  Of course, it's generally pretty evil to create a tag named `master`, but why be sloppy?  Having a `refs/notes/master` would be quite reasonable and would also break these deployment scripts.

Fixing *that* is not difficult either: simply make sure the reference name *begins with* `refs/heads/` and *goes on to conclude with* your desired branch name.  For instance:

```
while read ohash nhash refname; do
    case "$refname" in
    refs/heads/master) deploy master $ohash $nhash;;
    refs/heads/test?) deploy ${refname#refs/heads/} $ohash $nhash;;
    # ignore all others
    esac
done
```

(where `deploy` is an appropriate shell function).

If you really want just the *last* **branch** (ignoring tags and notes), though:

```
update=  # by default, nothing
while read ohash nhash refname; do
    case "$refname" in
    refs/heads/*) update=$nhash;;
    # ignore all others
    esac
done
if [ -n "$update" ]; then deploybyhash $update; fi
```

where "deploybyhash" does the obvious thing.  (This is such an *odd* thing to want, that I leave it to you to implement it—and to figure out when it's an especially bad idea; see the next deploy example.)

The really tricky part is a good multi-branch deployment function.  This one is quite untested, but probably correct:

```
# deploy - deploy a branch to a per-branch deployment area
# arguments: $1 - branch name, $2 - old hash, $3 - new hash
deploy() {
    local branch=$1 ohash=$2 nhash=$3 op tree

    if expr $ohash : '00*$' >/dev/null; then
        op=create
    elif expr $nhash : '00*$' >/dev/null; then
        op=delete
    else
        op=update
    fi
    # if creating or deleting a branch, probably should
    # not do anything here
    if [ $op != update ]; then
        echo $op branch $branch - no deployment action
        return
    fi
    # check whether there's a place to deploy this branch
    tree=/path/for/deployment/$branch
    if [ -d $tree ]; then
        # set up a per-branch index, except maybe for master
        # (this does it for all deployed branches)
        export GIT_INDEX_FILE="$GIT_DIR/index.$branch"
        # if there's no index yet, create it from the tree
        [ -f "$GIT_INDEX_FILE" ] || git --work-tree=$tree reset
        # and check out the appropriate commit w/o changing HEAD
        git --work-tree=$tree read-tree --reset -u $nhash
        unset GIT_INDEX_FILE # clean up after ourselves
    else
        echo "deployment tree $tree is missing, not checking it out"
    fi
}
```

It could be made substantially fancier, but it does the key items:

- Of course, we need multiple deployment areas (`$tree`).
- Since there is more than one deployment branch, we must use more than one index file, or otherwise rebuild the index every time.  This code uses one index per deployment area (`$GIT_INDEX_FILE`).
- It's probably best not to alter HEAD when updating a non-`master` tree, so we avoid `git checkout`.  Using `git read-tree --reset -u` updates our index and work tree from the specified commit hash.
- If the branch itself has just been deleted, we cannot check anything out.  If it has just been created, that might be OK: this is something you may want to tune.  You might want to create the tree for this case, for instance.  You might want to *delete* the deployment tree on branch deletion, for that matter.  The places and ways to do this should be obvious.

Comment: Can I instead specify which branch to process? as in hard code a specific branch and make the process simple?

Comment: Of course. Look at my very first code fragment that reads `stdin`: it checks for branches named `master` or `test`-plus-any-single-character. But if you are going to deploy more than one branch to *more than one directory,* you need to be careful with the index, because a server-side bare repository still has just the one standard index, and you plan to deploy to *two* (or more) directories.